# PHPUnit Installation Error

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

When running my Pear phpunit/PHPUnit install - this is the error I get

> Starting to download YAML-1.0.6.tgz (10,010 bytes)
> .....done: 10,010 bytes
> package.xml version "2.1" is not supported, only 1.0 and 2.0 are supported.
>
> Download of "symfony/YAML" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 4):

You most likely have an old version of Pear.

Try running the following

```
pear upgrade PEAR
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue and ended up reinstalling symfony/YAML and it worked, my error was:

```
 phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "symfony/YAML" (version >= 1.0.2, version <= 1.0.2), installed version is 1.0.6
```

So I uninstalled:

```
sudo pear uninstall symfony/YAML
```

From that I reinstalled the version it wanted

```
sudo pear install symfony/YAML-1.0.2
```

And re-ran the install:

```
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
"install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.12"
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on CentOS 5.8 after following http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/installation.html, I resolved it with

> pear upgrade --force PEAR
>
> pear list

which resulted in

```
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.10  stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.1   stable
PEAR             1.9.4   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
XML_RPC          1.5.5   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
```

allowing me to successfully run

> pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

resulting in

```
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator-1.3.1
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/Text_Template-1.1.1
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Timer-1.0.2
install ok: channel://pear.symfony-project.com/YAML-1.0.6
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_TokenStream-1.1.3
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage-1.1.3
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.1
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.12
```